# tar: file changed as we read it

Tags: makefile, tar

I am using `make` and `tar` to backup. When executing makefile, tar command shows `file changed as we read it`. In this case,

- the tar package is ok when the warning comes up
- but it stops the tar command for the following backup
- the file showing the warning in fact doesn't change -- it is really strange that the warning comes up
- the files showing the warning come up randomly, I mean, everytime I run my makefile, the files showing the warning are different
- `--ignore-failed-read` doesn't help. I am using tar 1.23 in MinGW
- I just changed my computer to WIN7 64 bit. The script works well in old WIN7 32 bit. But the tar version is not as new as the 1.23.

How can I stop the tar's warning to stop my backup following the warning?

---

**Edit-2**: it might be the reason

As I said above, the bash shell script worked well in my old computer. Comparing with the old computer, the `msys` version is different. So is the version of tar command. In the old computer, tar is 1.13.19 and it is 1.23 in the new computer. I copied the old tar command without copying its dependency msys-1.0.dll to the new computer and renamed it tar_old. And I also updated the tar command in the shell script and run the script. Then everything is ok. So, it seemed that the problem is the tar command. I am sure that there is no any file changed when taring. Is it a bug for tar command in new version? I don't know.

---

**Edit-1**: add more details

The backup is invoked by a bash shell script. It scans the target directory and builds makefile then invokes make to use tar command for backup. Followed is a typical makefile built by the bash shell script.

```
#--------------------------------------------
# backup VC
#--------------------------------------------
# the program for packing
PACK_TOOL=tar

# the option for packing tool
PACK_OPTION=cjvf

# M$: C driver
WIN_C_DIR=c:

# M$: D driver
WIN_D_DIR=d:

# M$: where the software is
WIN_PRG_DIR=wuyu/tools
# WIN_PRG_DIR=

# where to save the backup files
BAKDIR=/home/Wu.Y/MS_bak_MSYS

VC_FRAMEWORK=/home/Wu.Y/MS_bak_MSYS/tools/VC/VC_framework.tar.bz2
VC_2010=/home/Wu.Y/MS_bak_MSYS/tools/VC/VC_2010.tar.bz2

.PHONY: all

all: $(VC_FRAMEWORK) $(VC_2010)

$(VC_FRAMEWORK): $(WIN_C_DIR)/$(WIN_PRG_DIR)/VC/Framework/*
    @$(PACK_TOOL) $(PACK_OPTION) "$@" --ignore-failed-read /c/$(WIN_PRG_DIR)/VC/Framework
$(VC_2010): $(WIN_C_DIR)/$(WIN_PRG_DIR)/VC/VS2010/*
    @$(PACK_TOOL) $(PACK_OPTION) "$@" --ignore-failed-read /c/$(WIN_PRG_DIR)/VC/VS2010
```

As you can see, the tar package is stored in ~/MS_bak_MSYS/tools/VC/VC_2010.tar.bz2. I run the script in ~/qqaa. `~/MS_bak_MSYS` is excluded from tar command. So, the tar file I am creating is not inside a directory I am trying to put into tar file. This is why I felt it strange that the warning came up.

Comment: It looks like you are using windows setup, so not relevant for you.
Yet, we have similar problem when underlying filesystem is glusterfs. It looks like there is a bug when lstat and fstat return different values: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1058526

Comment: Got this problem using tar on a volume mounted by windows docker. Exchanging the `tar` utility for `pax` worked for me.

Comment: See the answer below for information about the difference in functionality between tar 1.35+ and previous versions if tar throws this error "for no good reason"

Answer (score 111):

I also encounter the tar messages "changed as we read it". For me these message occurred when I was making tar file of Linux file system in bitbake build environment. This error was sporadic.

For me this was not due to creating tar file from the same directory. I am assuming there is actually some file overwritten or changed during tar file creation.

The message is a warning and it still creates the tar file. We can still suppress these warning message by setting option

`--warning=no-file-changed`

(http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/warnings.html
)

Still the exit code return by the tar is "1" in warning message case:
http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/Synopsis.html

So if we are calling the tar file from some function in scripts, we can handle the exit code something like this:

```
set +e 
tar -czf sample.tar.gz dir1 dir2
exitcode=$?

if [ "$exitcode" != "1" ] && [ "$exitcode" != "0" ]; then
    exit $exitcode
fi
set -e
```

Comment: I have the same issue and this answer "solved" my problem by giving me the ability to work around it. Thanks @sandeep.

Comment: Tar exts with `1`: "If tar was given \`--create', \`--append' or \`--update' option, this exit code means that some files were changed while being archived and so the resulting archive does not contain the exact copy of the file set." This is such jaw-dropping bad behavior -- it will kill a pipeline and there's no way to stop it. *facepalm*

Comment: Note @Otheus `set +e`

Comment: @RyanBrodie I was thinking along the lines of `set -o pipefail; tar ... | gzip`. But I take it back; it won't kill the entire pipeline, because the exit is deferred until end of execution.

Comment: This is not a warning, it's an error. A warning would not cause a non-zero exitcode.

Comment: @Otheus, the fact that it exits with a non-zero code is valid. A file was changed during processing. When you create an archive, generally you want to be sure of its integrity. If you have automated processes running through a pipe where this could become an issue, you could make that into a script instead and do any error handling that fits your case.

Answer (score 98):

Although its very late but I recently had the same issue.

Issue is because dir `.` is changing as `xyz.tar.gz` is created after running the command. There are two solutions:

**Solution 1:**
`tar` will not mind if the archive is created in any directory inside `.`. There can be reasons why can't create the archive outside the work space. Worked around it by creating a temporary directory for putting the archive as:

```
mkdir artefacts
tar -zcvf artefacts/archive.tar.gz --exclude=./artefacts .
echo $?
0
```

**Solution 2:**
This one I like. create the archive file before running tar:

```
touch archive.tar.gz
tar --exclude=archive.tar.gz -zcvf archive.tar.gz .
echo $?
0
```

Comment: In solution 2, just put the `--exclude=archive.tar.gz` before the other optiosn `-zvcf` and it actually works nicely.

Comment: It doesn't, I am getting the same warning.

Comment: The key point of the second solution is the `touch archive.tar.gz`, if it doesn't exist when you wanna run `tar` command, it won't work

Answer (score 43):

If you want help debugging a problem like this you need to provide the make rule or at least the tar command you invoked.  How can we see what's wrong with the command if there's no command to see?

However, 99% of the time an error like this means that you're creating the tar file inside a directory that you're trying to put into the tar file.  So, when tar tries to read the directory it finds the tar file as a member of the directory, starts to read it and write it out to the tar file, and so between the time it starts to read the tar file and when it finishes reading the tar file, the tar file has changed.

So for example something like:

```
tar cf ./foo.tar .
```

There's no way to "stop" this, because it's not wrong.  Just put your tar file somewhere else when you create it, or find another way (using `--exclude` or whatever) to omit the tar file.

Comment: I added more details in the original post. Please check.

Comment: Based on the info here I don't know what's wrong.  However, I know very little about working with Windows or cygwin... I do know that the Windows filesystem is _much_ more difficult to work with WRT multiple programs accessing the same file than a POSIX-based filesystem.  But that doesn't seem immediately relevant to your situation.  All I can suggest is removing the `@` in your rules and examining the command that make is printing to be sure it's correct, and look at the files tar is trying to create (output from the v option) to ensure there's nothing mysterious.

Answer (score 23):

Here is a one-liner for ignoring the tar exit status if it is 1. There is no need to `set +e` as in [sandeep's script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24012292/1070890). If the tar exit status is 0 or 1, this one-liner will return with exit status 0. Otherwise it will return with exit status 1. This is different from [sandeep's script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24012292/1070890) where the original exit status value is preserved if it is different from 1.

`tar -czf sample.tar.gz dir1 dir2 || [[ $? -eq 1 ]]`

Comment: Why wouldn't you want the original exit status to be preserved?

Comment: My most common use case is shell scripts in Jenkins. Jenkins by defaults runs scripts with the `errexit` option set, i.e. any failing command will cause the script to exit immediately. That is a problem when you run e.g. system tests and want the Jenkins job to run to the end and report all failed tests instead of bailing out when a system test fails.

Comment: this just ignores the return code of 1 it does not fix issue of why the tar compression failed in the middle ... when you get a 1 typically the tar failed to complete so its output archive will not have all of the source data only partial data

Answer (score 6):

To enhance Fabian's one-liner; let us say that we want to ignore only exit status 1 but to preserve the exit status if it is anything else:

```
tar -czf sample.tar.gz dir1 dir2 || ( export ret=$?; [[ $ret -eq 1 ]] || exit "$ret" )
```

This does everything sandeep's script does, on one line.

Answer (score 5):

Simply using an **outer directory** for the output, solved the problem for me.

```
sudo tar czf ./../31OCT18.tar.gz ./
```

Comment: If putting the new tar in the same folder you are compressing, it changes lol

Comment: looks like it's creating the tar in the parent folder

Answer (score 2):

Its important to check what version of tar you have

```
tar --version
```

Then read the relevant section below [esp. if you are at tar 1.34 or before].

## tar 1.34 or before

These versions of tar use the "ctime" flag from stat, which is derived from inodes' ctime.

Note ctime changes anytime the inodes' metadata changes, and the metadata includes innocuous data such "last accessed time" as well as "number of hard links to file".

Here is the block from 1.26's src/create.c

```c
   if ((timespec_cmp (get_stat_ctime (&final_stat), original_ctime) != 0
      /* Original ctime will change if the file is a directory and
 --remove-files is given */
      && !(remove_files_option && is_dir))
     || original_size < final_stat.st_size)
   {
     WARNOPT (WARN_FILE_CHANGED,
      (0, 0, _("%s: file changed as we read it"),
quotearg_colon (p)));
     set_exit_status (TAREXIT_DIFFERS);
   }
```

And some links about what ctime is:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_(system_call)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257099/what-does-when-the-files-status-was-last-changed-mean
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode

## tar 1.35+

In these versions, tar uses "mtime" [aka modified time] from the inode, as reflected in the change log entry:

```
2022-06-10  Paul Eggert  <eggert@cs.ucla.edu>

    Warn “file changed as we read it” less often

    * src/create.c (dump_file0): Remove an fstatat call that is
    unnecessary because the file wasn’t read so we can treat
    the first
    fstatat as atomic.  Warn “file changed” when the file’s
    size,
    mtime, user ID, group ID, or mode changes, instead of when the
    file’s size or ctime changes.  Also, when such a change happens,
    do not change exit status if --ignore-failed-read.  Finally,
    don’t
    attempt to change atime back if it didn’t change.
```

And the code in question [still in src/create.c]

```c
         Do not check atime which is saved only to replace it later.
         Do not check ctime where changes might be benign (e.g.,
         another process creates a hard link to the file).  */

      /* If the file's user ID, group ID or mode changed, tar may
         have output the wrong info for the file.  */
      ok &= st1.st_uid == st2.st_uid;
      ok &= st1.st_gid == st2.st_gid;
      ok &= st1.st_mode == st2.st_mode;

      /* Likewise for the file's mtime, but skip this check if it
         is a directory possibly updated by --remove-files.  */
      if (! (is_dir && remove_files_option))
        ok &= ! timespec_cmp (get_stat_mtime (&st1),
                  get_stat_mtime (&st2));
```

Therefore, if you are struggling with this error, I suggest trying tar 1.35 and see if that resolves the issue.

For me, other processes on the box were disrupting a tar 1.25 archive creation through no fault of their own.

Comment: I upvoted this answer not because it is a great answer to the question, but because it mentioned the ctime/mtime being updated as the trigger of the error message.
I'm running tar on cygwin and there are some things that behave a bit different than what we're used to in "native" POSIX environments.

Comment: Hi @MattBianco - I posted the answer since it provides some contextual information about where this error comes from in tar.    This question has become the canonical one in stack overflow for this error, others are being closed as duplicate.   So while the answer is slightly mismatched, I believe people researching this error are being sent to this page even if the conditions that they are experience under are different.   If there's a different question on StackOverflow where I can post the answer, I'd be interested to know it.

Comment: @MattBianco - for example, this is a more generic question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45750425/unix-tar-returning-file-changed-as-we-read-it], but is closed as duplicate and is redirecting here.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to say that I found the answer helpful, and that's the reason why I gave it an upvote. Indeed it was a search engine that sent me, but your answer made me realize that ctime/mtime changes could cause the "error". Perhaps by files being added to the source directory being read by tar. Which in the end gave me ideas for a better solution design which is now in place.

Answer (score 1):

Exit codes for `tar` are restricted, so you don't get to much information.
You *can* assume that `ec=1` is safe to ignore, but it might trip - i.e. the `gzip`-example in other posts (exit code from external programs).

The ***reason*** for the `file changed as we read it` error/warning can be varying.

- A *log file* inside the directory.
- Writing to a `tar` file in the same directory you are trying to back up.
- etc.

Possible workarounds can involve:

- *exclude* known files (log files, tar-files, etc)
- ensure log files are written to other directories

This can be quite involved, so you might want to still just run the tar command and preferably *safely* ignore *some* errors / warnings.

To do this you will have to:

- Save the `tar` output.
- Save the exit code
- Check the output against known warnings and errors, not unlike `tar`'s own ignore.
- **Conditionally** pass another exit code to the next program in the pipe.

In OP's case this would have to be wrapped in a script and run as `PACK_TOOL`.

```sh
# List of errors and warnings from "tar" which we will safely ignore.
# Adapt to your findings and needs
IGNORE_ERROR="^tar:.*(Removing leading|socket ignored|file changed as we read it)"

# Save stderr from "tar"
RET=$(tar zcf $BACKUP --exclude Cache --exclude output.log --exclude "*cron*sysout*" $DIR 2>&1)
EC=$?  # Save "tar's" exit code
echo "$RET"
if [ $EC -ne 0 ]
then
  # Check the RET output, remove (grep -v) any errors / warning you wish to ignore
  REAL_ERRORS=$(echo "$RET" | grep "^tar: " | grep -Ev "${IGNORE_ERROR:?}")
  # If there is any output left you actually got an error to check
  if [ -n "$REAL_ERRORS" ]
  then
      echo "ERROR during backup of ${DIR:?} to ${BACKUP:?}"
  else
      echo "OK backup of (warnings ignored) ${DIR:?}"
      EC=0
  fi
else
  echo "OK backup of ${DIR:?}"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by adding a simple sleep timeout of 20 sec.
This might happen if your source directory is still writing. Hence put a sleep so that the backup would finish and then tar should work fine. This also helped me in getting the right exit status.

```
sleep 20
tar -czf ${DB}.${DATE}.tgz ./${DB}.${DATE}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure does it suit you but I noticed that `tar` does not fail on changed/deleted files in pipe mode. See what I mean.

Test script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -ex
tar cpf - ./files | aws s3 cp - s3://my-bucket/files.tar
echo $?
```

Deleting random files manually...

Output:

```
+ aws s3 cp - s3://my-bucket/files.tar
+ tar cpf - ./files
tar: ./files/default_images: File removed before we read it
tar: ./files: file changed as we read it
+ echo 0
0
```

Comment: This is because exit codes are ignored inside of pipes by default. And it is a good practice to enable them back by "set -o pipefail".

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error when I was trying to create an archive of the same folder as where I put the file in. To solve this, I made my shell resolve the paths instead of passing the whole directory:

```
tar czf release.tar.gz ./*
```

This makes the `tar` command never see its own archive when creating it, which fixes the error

Answer (score -1):

**Answer should be very simple:** Don't save your tar file while "Taring" it in the same directory.

Just do: `tar -cvzf resources/docker/php/php.tar.gz .`

Eventually,

> it will tar the current directory and save it to another directory.

That's easy peasy, lemon squeezy fellas