# tar: "file changed as we read it" occurring for large linked files

Tags: linux, tar

I'm using the method described in [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/Applications.html) to transfer files with `tar` and sometimes I'm getting this error:

```
tar: ./file.large: file changed as we read it
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

The executed command is the following:

> % tar -C somedir -chf - . | tar -xf -

This is happening depending on file size with this setup (after pruning the error case to the bare minimum):

```
% tree -s -A
.
├── [ 29980317]  file.large
└── [     4096]  somedir
    └── [       13]  file.large -> ../file.large
```

This error seems obviously related with the fact that the transferred file is a symbolic link to the file being overwritten, however if the file is small (a few bytes is enough), the `tar` command is executed without any error.

What I need is the original file overwritten with the de-referenced symbolic link (in my original application I'm using also --backup in the second `tar`) or the linked file to be skipped, but I couldn't find a way to do the latter.

Is there a setting that controls this behavior or a workaround?

I'm using tar 1.13.25 on RHEL 5.3 (Linux 2.6.18-128.el5 x86_64).

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the target file referenced by the link does not actually change? If it is a log file of some sort, maybe there is a process which keeps appending to it while you're running tar.

Comment: The file in question is not a log nor output file, it actually is an input file that is not changed. My guess is that the file changes by tar itself and for some reason that is not an issue when the file is small.

Comment: Have a look at the comment about tar versions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318852/tar-file-changed-as-we-read-it . The algorithm changes starting in tar 1.35