# Ansible - is there an elegant way to tar.gz and rsync a large directory?

Tags: tar, ansible, gzip

I'm trying to avoid a list of 'command' modules in my ansible play, but there seems to be a void of ansible docs regarding tar/gz and the synch module seems... incomplete.

I'd like to gzip a tarball of a big directory then rsync it to another host. Even using 'command' seems to  not work for me :<

```
 "warnings": ["Consider using unarchive module rather than running tar"]}
 [WARNING]: Consider using unarchive module rather than running tar


PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
ctarlctarl                 : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

The '[unarchive](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/unarchive_module.html)' module seems to expect an already compressed/archived directory and doesn't appear to be the solution I want.

Related but unanswered: [ansible playbook unable to continue as the `tar` fails due to `file change as we read`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35023608/ansible-playbook-unable-to-continue-as-the-tar-fails-due-to-file-change-as-we)

(Edit) showing the task since it was asked if I remembered the z. =)

```
  - name: tar ball app dir, exclude conf files
    command: "tar -zcvf {{ item.code_dir }}.tar.gz --exclude '*config*' ."
    args:
      chdir:  "{{ apps_home }}/{{ item.code_dir }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ processes }}"
```

Comment: These command warnings of ansible are rather dump. They just check the first word in a command and if it matches a list it will complain. It does not take into account that you can do much more with the `tar` command than unarchiving... You can avoid the warning by: `- command: \`which tar\` ...`

Comment: But that warning only is a warning. The fail comes form something else.

Comment: you remembered the -z right?

Answer (score 2):

Starting from version 2.3 Ansible has the `archive` module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/archive_module.html

Since Ansible version 8.4 this module was moved to `community.general` collection:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/archive_module.html

Also, you can use the [`synchronize`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html) module to avoid calling `rsync` via `command`.

With that you can archive, transfer and unarchive all with Ansible modules and don't have to fiddle with command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

So, I got it working... just inelegantly.

1. With the v flag set, my ansible stdout was horrendously verbose (even without calling -vvvv with ansible-playbook). Turning off the switch inside the tar command made tracking down the problem easier.
2. The problem was actually the error "error: file changed as we read it" - no doubt because I was adding the archive file into the directory it was compressing. I solved it by simply moving the archived file up a directory when running.

This, however, leaves me with the 'command after command' solution - which is what I hope I'll eventually be able to avoid. Half way there, though.

Answer (score -1):

This warning tip you can use the ansible unarchive module instead of tar commnad. The syntax is very easy just like below:

```
- unarchive: src=foo.tgz dest=/var/lib/foo
```

And more detail info you can got from here: [unarchive_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/unarchive_module.html)

Comment: OP wants to create an archive and already mentioned `unarchive` is not what he wants