# tar exclude error-output on specific paths

Tags: linux, unix, tar

Is it possible to ignore error-messages like: `/etc/some-tool/some-log: file changed as we read it` on the same way you can use exclude to exclude files?

I'm using tar to do system-backups, redirecting stdout and stderr into log-files. I Got some direcotires which contain log-files. Simply don't want to have the same error-lines (like shown above) every day in my result file.

So far couldn't find a command on `man tar` which could help me.

Comment: Check out the `--warning=no-file-changed` option. (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24012292/1328439)

Comment: I'll go with this and see if it helps me. Unfortunately I can't test it right now. For my understandings I would say I have to use the keyword `file-changed` instead of `no-file-changed`, but we will see this soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a script which analyzes the output log and decides if it's an error or not. Ignoring warnings on a global scope is not what I was looking for. Took me some time but it's the safest method imo.